# How to Move a Twilio Audio Recording File to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio

I am struggling with understanding how best to stream a file to Amazon S3. I would like to hit a Twilio endpoint, GET the mp3 recording located there, pass it through my Node app and on to Amazon S3.

I have looked at several npm streaming/s3 libraries, but I cannot find a good example of how to incorporate the GET request for the file into the process.

The function below will capture the mp3 file and save it on my server and upload a file to Amazon S3. The file is correct on my server but the Amazon S3 version seems to be empty(20kb) and is unplayable when downloaded.

I think I am going about this all wrong. The AWS S3 sdk implies this can be done without an additional library. Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using Node, npm request and the aws skd here.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports = {
  postFile : function(req,res){
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  request
    .get('http://theTwilioRecordingUrl.mp3')
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log("ERROR");
    })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("mydownloadedFile.mp3"));

  s3.upload({
    Bucket: 'bucketname',
    Key: 'myuploadedfilename.mp3',
    Body:"mydownloadedFile.mp3"}, function(err,data){
  if(err){
    console.log("AMAZON UPLOAD ERROR", err);
  } else {
     console.log("AMAZON UPLOAD SUCCESS",data);
  }
  });
  res.status(200).end();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio does additional processing with each request to a [recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording), so we cannot make public S3 Urls available. Taking a local copy from Twilio's Url and saving to S3 is the best way to move your recordings to your own bucket.